# How to find values shared between groups in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a tidy data.frame with two columns: `exp` and `val`. I want to find which values of `val` are shared among all different experiments.

```
df <- data.frame(exp = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'),
                 val = c(10, 20, 15, 10, 10, 15, 99, 2, 15, 20, 10, 4))
df

   exp val
1    A  10
2    A  20
3    A  15
4    A  10
5    B  10
6    B  15
7    B  99
8    B   2
9    C  15
10   C  20
11   C  10
12   C   4
```

Expected result could be either a vector of values:

```
10, 15
```

or a column on the data frame telling if that value is shared:

```
   exp     val shared
   <fct> <dbl> <lgl> 
 1 A        10 TRUE  
 2 A        20 FALSE 
 3 A        15 TRUE  
 4 A        10 TRUE  
 5 B        10 TRUE  
 6 B        15 TRUE  
 7 B        99 FALSE 
 8 B         2 FALSE 
 9 C        15 TRUE  
10 C        20 FALSE 
11 C        10 TRUE  
12 C         4 FALSE
```

I was able to find an answer (see the self-answer below) but this seems like a common enough question that there **must** be a better way than the really hacky solution I cam up with.

I tried to solve this problem in `dplyr` since that's what I'm familiar with, but I'm interested in any kind of solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or you can group by `val` and then check whether the number of distinct `exp` for that `val` is equal to the data frame level number of distinct `exp`:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(val) %>% 
    mutate(shared = n_distinct(exp) == n_distinct(.$exp))
    # notice the first exp refers to exp for each group while .$exp refers 
    # to the overall exp column in the data frame

# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   val [6]
#   exp     val shared
#   <fct> <dbl> <lgl> 
# 1 A        10 TRUE  
# 2 A        20 FALSE 
# 3 A        15 TRUE  
# 4 A        10 TRUE  
# 5 B        10 TRUE  
# 6 B        15 TRUE  
# 7 B        99 FALSE 
# 8 B         2 FALSE 
# 9 C        15 TRUE  
#10 C        20 FALSE 
#11 C        10 TRUE  
#12 C         4 FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew there must be something simple like that. Is there any reason I can't replace `df$exp` with `.$exp` to make it more portable? It seems to give the same result when I try it.

Comment: Yes. You can use `.$exp`, it should work the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Using base R you can use `table`:

```
as.numeric(colnames(a<-table(df))[colSums(a>0)==nrow(a)])
[1] 10 15
```

you can also do:

```
df %>%
   mutate(s = val %in% as.numeric(colnames(a<-table(df))[colSums(a>0)==nrow(a)]))
   exp val     s
1    A  10  TRUE
2    A  20 FALSE
3    A  15  TRUE
4    A  10  TRUE
5    B  10  TRUE
6    B  15  TRUE
7    B  99 FALSE
8    B   2 FALSE
9    C  15  TRUE
10   C  20 FALSE
11   C  10  TRUE
12   C   4 FALSE
```

Comment: Or `as.numeric(names(x <- !colSums(!table(df)))[x])`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an other base R solution:

```
x <- split(df$val, df$exp)
Reduce(intersect, x)
## [1] 10 15
```

Answer (score 0):

We can go through the data.frame row by row and count up how many times that row's value is found in the vector `df$val`.

To deal with possible repeat values, we have to use `group_by %>% distinct` to remove repeated values of `val` within groups. But then to get just the values of `val` as a vector, we need to `ungroup %>% select(val) %>% unlist`, which just seems needlessly complicated.

Finally, we can check whether the number of groups the value is found in equals the total number of groups.

```
df %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(num_groups = sum(group_by(., exp) %>%
                                distinct(val) %>%
                                ungroup() %>%
                                select(val) %>%
                                unlist() %in% val),
           shared = num_groups == length(unique(.$exp)))


# A tibble: 12 x 4
   exp     val num_groups shared
   <fct> <dbl>      <int> <lgl> 
 1 A        10          3 TRUE  
 2 A        20          2 FALSE 
 3 A        15          3 TRUE  
 4 A        10          3 TRUE  
 5 B        10          3 TRUE  
 6 B        15          3 TRUE  
 7 B        99          1 FALSE 
 8 B         2          1 FALSE 
 9 C        15          3 TRUE  
10 C        20          2 FALSE 
11 C        10          3 TRUE  
12 C         4          1 FALSE
```