# Retrieve data that has the same factor in column B for both factors in column A and finding which assets that male does not share with female

Tags: r, filter

In column A, there are two factors, male and female.
In column B, there are 5 assets, a to e.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1:7),                                   
                 gender = c("male","male", "male", "female", "female","female","female"),               
                 assets = c("a,e","a,b,e,d", "b,c,e","b,c,e", "a,b,e,d", "c,d","a,d"))
```

How do I retrieve data where both male and female shared the same asset combinations?

I've zero clue how to write the R syntax for it and below is what I have tried

```
sameassets <- df %>% filter(filter(gender="male",assets) == filter(gender="female",assets))
```

desired output

```
sameassests <- data.frame(ID = c(2,5,3,4),                                   
                          gender = c("male", "female", "male", "female"),               
                          assets = c("a,b,e,d", "a,b,e,d", "b,c,e","b,c,e"))
```

Can someone help please?

Edit to include additional question.
I also want to find out which asset combination that male does not share with female.

So the desired output for this will look like

```
diffassests <- data.frame(ID = c(1,6,7),                                   
                              gender = c("male", "female", "female"),               
                              assets = c("a,e", "c,d", "a,d"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df %>%
   group_by(assets) %>%
   filter(all(c('male', 'female') %in% gender))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   assets [2]
     ID gender assets 
  <int> <chr>  <chr>  
1     2 male   a,b,e,d
2     3 male   b,c,e  
3     4 female b,c,e  
4     5 female a,b,e,d
```

Comment: Thanks @onyambu. Is it possible to compute the output so that the same assets are grouped together, a,b,e,d together and then b, c, e, in other words, the order of the ID is 2, 5, 3, 4? Your answer gives 2, 3, 4, 5.

Comment: btw if I want to find the difference how can i make it work? I tried adding ! but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244211/discussion-between-catalyst-and-onyambu).

Comment: Reposting it here. Currently we have a, b, e, d and b, c, e. How do I compute output that gives 1) a, e 2) a, b, e, d 3) c, d 4) a, d? Or mismatch?

Comment: Hi @onyambu, not needed for my initial question. I have edited the post to include my 2nd question. Hopefully that clarifies the confusion. Thanks again ;)

Comment: @Catalyst save the results from this post as `df1` then just do `anti_join(df, df1)` should give you your needed results

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to first group by `assets`, then determine whether the number of distinct `gender` for that `assets` is equal to the dataframe level number of distinct `gender`. The first `gender` refers to `gender` for each group, then `.$gender` refers to the overall `gender` column. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51848692/15293191) for original idea.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(assets) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(gender) == n_distinct(.$gender))
```

Or a possible base R solution:

```
df[df$assets %in% Reduce(intersect, split(df$assets, df$gender)), ]
```

**Output**

```
     ID gender assets 
  <int> <chr>  <chr>  
1     2 male   a,b,e,d
2     3 male   b,c,e  
3     4 female b,c,e  
4     5 female a,b,e,d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by grouping by `assets` and then filtering to remove any asset groups that have only one row, as in:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(ID = c(1:7),                                   
                 gender = c("male","male", "male", "female", "female","female","female"),               
                 assets = c("a,e","a,b,e,d", "b,c,e","b,c,e", "a,b,e,d", "c,d","a,d"))  

df |> 
  group_by(assets) |> 
  filter(n() > 1) |> 
  arrange(assets, ID)
```

Comment: Note that this will fail whenever there is one type of gender within one group. eg it will fail in the case of `df1 <- rbind(df[1,], df)`